# (Scripting) Import & assign material from another blend file

Tags: scripting

I am trying to import materials from another blend file and assign the nth material to the active object.
I have tried multiple solutions but I always hit errors.

## Approach 1

Here the error is: "list indices must be integers or slices, not str" (in the approach shown below):

with bpy.data.libraries.load(path) as (data_from, data_to):

```
     data_to.materials = data_from.materials
     mat = data_to.materials
     cnt=0
     for m in data_to.materials:
        cnt=cnt+1
        if (cnt>1): 
         break  
        # Assign material
        obj=bpy.context.scene.objects.active
        material1 = data_to.materials[cnt]
        obj.active_material = data_to.materials[material1]
```

## Approach 2

When I try to assign the material by using an index instead the error is: "bpy_struct: item.attr = val: Object.active_material expected a Material type, not str" (in the approach shown below):
obj.active_material = data_to.materials[cnt]

I guess, I haven't fully understood what data_from/data_to objects are and how to use them. Can somebody help me here?

Thanks in advance,

Gemor

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`data_from` are just string lists, in this case, the names of materials in the Blend file designated by the path. `data_to` is a string list of the names of the materials you want to be loaded. So, whatever names you put in `data_to.materials` will be loaded from the designated Blend file's material data block into the current material data block. After that, you access those materials in the material data block, i.e., `bpy.data.materials`. So, your code should read:

```
with bpy.data.libraries.load(path) as (data_from, data_to):

    data_to.materials = data_from.materials
    mat = data_to.materials
    cnt=0
    for m in data_to.materials:
        cnt=cnt+1
        if (cnt>1): 
            break  
        # Assign material
        obj=bpy.context.scene.objects.active
        material1 = bpy.data.materials[mat[cnt]]
        obj.active_material = material1
```

Note that this could give unexpected results if a material name already exists in the material data block.

Comment: Thank you cmomoney, that clarifies it. Now I know what to do.